# regex for remove all strings starts with run and ends with :

Tags: regex, sed

Log:

```
runHalfMarathon ==>> 44 :: runFullMarathon ==>> 21 :: Name ==>> Suresh :: Age ==>> 21 ::
```

Regex:

```
sed 's/run* ==>> [0-9]* //g' -i sample.log
```

Its not working. I want to remove all strings starts with run

Expected output:

```
Name ==>> Suresh :: Age ==>> 21 ::
```

Please help.

Comment: It won't work because `n*` matches 0 or more `n` symbols. You must have meant `[^=]*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work because `n*` matches 0 or more `n` symbols. If you use `.*`, then you can remove too much of the string.

I suggest using replacing `*` with `[^=]*` (that will match zero or more characters other than a `=`) and add  `*:: *` at the end to also remove `::` with spaces around:

```
sed 's/run[^=]* ==>> [0-9]* *:: *//g'
```

See [this demo](https://ideone.com/V2GuNR).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
sed -r 's/.+?Name/Name/g'
```

The `.+?Name` looks for anything up to and including Name. We then replace everything we found with only `Name` meaning we effectively get rid of the previous parts.

Note the options passed to `sed`:

```
-r use extended regular expressions in the script
```

Example data:

```
$ cat m
runHalfMarathon ==>> 44 :: runFullMarathon ==>> 21 :: Name ==>> Suresh :: Age ==>> 21 ::
runHalfMarathon ==>> 44 :: runFullMarathon ==>> 21 :: Name ==>> foo :: Age ==>> 20 ::
runHalfMarathon ==>> 44 :: runFullMarathon ==>> 21 :: Name ==>> bar :: Age ==>> 1 ::
runHalfMarathon ==>> 44 :: runFullMarathon ==>> 21 :: Name ==>> baz :: Age ==>> 0 ::
```

Example output:

```
$ cat m | sed -r 's/.+?Name/Name/g'
Name ==>> Suresh :: Age ==>> 21 ::
Name ==>> foo :: Age ==>> 20 ::
Name ==>> bar :: Age ==>> 1 ::
Name ==>> baz :: Age ==>> 0 ::
```